# React stateless component where map function is not returning

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a stateless component form helper that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default(props) => {
    var { attr, fieldAttribute } = props;
    var label = attr.label;
    var val = fieldAttribute.value;
    var keys = [];

    if( typeof val === 'object' ){
        keys = Object.keys( val );
    }

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">{label}</label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
                {(() => {
                    if( typeof val === 'object' ){
                        keys.map(function(k){
                            return (
                                <p className="form-control-static"><span className="label label-default label-fixed">{k}</span> {val[k]}</p>
                            )
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        return (
                            <p className="form-control-static">{val}</p>
                        )
                    }
                })()}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The data in 'val' is either a string or a json object (validated). My issue is with the keys.map()... it's not returning anything for some reason.

Data in 'val' in that case looks like:

```
{
    foo: 'some value of foo',
    bar: 'some value of bar
}
```

I've tried many different ways to iterate over 'val' to no success. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add `return` statement before `keys.map`, because you need return result from function., without `return` your function returns `undefined` and that's why you don't get any result

```
return keys.map(function(k){
   ..
});
```

Comment: omg, what a stupid omission... it 'was' late when I wrote that ha, thanks.